# DataTemplate key is ignored when specified with x:Static

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I encountered weird behavior with DataTemplate keys: when DataType is specified via x:Type, and x:Key is specified via x:Static reference, x:Key is ignored. I wrote sample app to illustrate it.

XAML resources:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type wpfApplication1:TestDto}" x:Key="{x:Static wpfApplication1:DataKeys.TestDtoKey}" />
<DataTemplate x:Key="{x:Static wpfApplication1:DataKeys.TestDtoKey2}" />
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type wpfApplication1:TestDto}" x:Key="TestKey3" />
<DataTemplate DataType="wpfApplication1:TestDto" x:Key="{x:Static wpfApplication1:DataKeys.TestDtoKey4}" />
```

C#:

```
public class TestDto {}

public static class DataKeys
{
    public static string TestDtoKey = "TestKey";
    public static string TestDtoKey2 = "TestKey2";
    public static string TestDtoKey4 = "TestKey4";
}
```

Launch application, see this.Resources.Keys in debugger:

```
{DataTemplateKey(WpfApplication1.TestDto)}  object {System.Windows.DataTemplateKey}
"TestKey2"  object {string}
"TestKey3"  object {string}
"TestKey4"  object {string}
```

As you can see, in first case x:Key is ignored!

Can someone explain what is going on? 
Documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.datatype.aspx) clearly says that setting x:Key will set resource key to whatever you specify in it.

Comment: Very similar to the bug. Maybe you should try to write feedback for connect.microsoft.com?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Short answer to your question is - YES it's a bug in WPF framework. Bug reported [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/806227/wpf-bug-in-defining-datatemplates-under-resource-section-with-x-static).

**Update** -

Microsoft has accepted that it's a bug in XAML compiler and they are not fixing this issue. Quote from Microsoft -

> This is an issue in the XAML compiler - it produces BAML to describe
>   the key for each resource, normally based on the x:Key if it's present
>   and on the DataType if it's not. When x:Key is itself indirect (in
>   your case, using x:Static), the compiler chooses the DataType key.
>   While choosing the x:Static-based key is probably more "correct",
>   changing this would introduce compatibility issues. Also, because the
>   issue occurs at compile-time, you'd have to recompile your app to see
>   the fix (to generate a different BAML stream). Existing copies of your
>   app would contain the old BAML stream, and would behave the same way
>   at runtime as they do now. For this reason we are deciding to won't
>   fix this issue.

x:Key is not ignored here but is set to `DataTemplateKey(WpfApplication1.TestDto)` in first case. You cannot have a resource declared under Resources section without a key value.

As you can see that key gets automatically set to `DataTemplateKey(WpfApplication1.TestDto)` here.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.datatype.aspx) -

> This property that is very similar to the TargetType property of the
>   Style class. **When you set this property to the data type without
>   specifying an x:Key, the DataTemplate gets applied automatically to
>   data objects of that type. Note that when you do that the x:Key is set
>   implicitly.** Therefore, if you assign this DataTemplate an x:Key value,
>   you are overriding the implicit x:Key and the DataTemplate would not
>   be applied automatically.

Somehow, in case you `bind x:Key with static value` instead of hardcoding string, it gets `defined as default template for that dataType` and hence key gets set to `DataTemplateKey(WpfApplication1.TestDto)`.

This you can verify by adding another DataTemplate to your resources with only DataType set i.e.

`<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type wpfApplication1:TestDto}"/>`.

It will compile fine but will throw runtime error

> "Item has already been added. Key in dictionary:
>   'DataTemplateKey(WpfApplication1.TestDto)'  Key being added:
>   'DataTemplateKey(WpfApplication1.TestDto)'"

Comment: Well, thank you for the answer, but you just told same thing as me in different words.

Comment: Yeah short answer to your question will be that's a bug. :)

Comment: Updated with microsoft response. They have accepted the defect and won't be fixing this because of compatibility issues.

Answer (score 1):

Im not shure that will help, but try to append {get;set;} to each property in your class. Some staff in WPF (i.e. Binding) does not works without them. May be here is the same story...

```
public static class DataKeys
{
  public static string TestDtoKey { get { return "TestKey"; } set; }
  public static string TestDtoKey2 { get { return "TestKey2"; } set; }
  public static string TestDtoKey4 { get { return "TestKey4"; } set; }
}
```

Comment: I tried it and, no wonder, it does not help. x:Static works with any static properties or fields.

Comment: [offtop] Nice nick :) [/offtop]